# Homedir inside homedir restricted access

Tags: unix, apache-http-server, chmod

On my VPS i've installed debian, apache+php. 
I have 2 users: `foo` and `bar`. 
 Apache is configured to execute php files from 
`/home/foo/htdocs`.

I created dir: `/home/foo/htdocs/bar/` and made it home dir for user `bar`. Hover, I need to make a restriction: `bar` can't read, write or executre any files outside his own dir, but Apache has to be able execute all php files from `/htdocs`.

I tried to `chown` the `bar` dir only for user bar, also experimented a lot with `chmod` but without a result so far.

If there's any better way to satisfy my needs don't hesitate to write about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to put `bar`'s web-facing files in `/home/bar/htdocs/` and then adding the following line to your `httpd.conf` to make it accessible at `http://example.com/bar/`:

```
Alias /bar /home/bar/htdocs
```

Be sure to configure a [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) section appropriately too.